# Can't access environment variable regardless it's successfully set

Tags: environment-variables

I've set an environment variable in Putty using:

```
export TEST_API_KEY='mykeydatahere'
```

I then restarted my Linode.

Running the following successfully displays the key:

```
echo $TEST_API_KEY
```

However, running the following in a php script doesn't show the key:

```
$key = getenv('TEST_API_KEY');
echo "Here's the key: " . $key;
```

It only displays:

```
Here's the key:
```

I've checked for

```
; Set environment variables
```

and also the key name in my FPM conf file, but neither are there.

Is there something else I need to do to be able to access the variable?

Someone suggested I need to use putenv in my php scripts, but hardcoding an api key into php scripts defeats the purpose of the safety of having the api key in an environment variable.

Thank you

Comment: This is a FAQ. Env vars are private to each process. When you export and env var in your shell it is only available to processes started by that shell. It is not available to other processes.

Comment: Thank you, Kurtis. So how would I make it available for any php script that I run?